# Evaluating limit of exponential product

Tags: limits, products

I have the following product to evaluate as a limit: 
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=-1}^n(r^{kr^k})$$
where $0<r<1$. 
Upon graphing this for various values of $r$, it seems that there is a finite limit depending on the value of $r$, namely decreasing $r$ gives a greater limit and vice versa. 
Any advice on how to evaluate this?

Comment: it looks like the elements in the product don't depend on $n$.

Comment: @DanielXiang Whoops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking logarithm of the product you get $\log r\sum_{k=-1}^nkr^k$.
Now $\sum_{k=0}^nkr^{k-1}$ is the sum$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^nx^k$ evaluated at $x=r$. Now for $|x|<1$, $\sum_{k=1}^nx^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.

Can you do the rest?

Comment: I think for $\sum_{k=1}^nx^k$ we have $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x(x-1)}$. When I used that, I was able to get the answer. Thank you for your help.